# AWS s3 sync, cp recursive throw error if object does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was using `aws s3 sync` and `aws cp --recursive` to copy a directory in s3 to local.

However I noticed that if a directory does not exist, the command does not throw an error at all.

`aws s3 sync s3://path/to/a/directory/that/does/not/exist localpath`

I expect the above command to throw an error, but that does not happen. Instead it creates an empty directory called localpath. How do I make it throw an error if the object does not exist in s3.

Comment: You can't. There is no such functionality. You would have to go back to get-object api.

Comment: since the functionality doesn't exist, you can do something like  `[[ -z $(aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/) ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"` , this command will check if the output is empty , if not empty it will execute `echo "no"`